# Android: How to set intent for native camera as landscape mode

Tags: android, camera, orientation, landscape

I have problem knowing how to set the intent to do orientation of the camera. Some guys say it impossible, even impossible setting the camera facing. I can set the camera facing below API 21 though.

Comment: Hi, are you looking to change the orientation of the preview from camera ?

Comment: Yes .. When start a native camera app, I want it to in landscape mode by default